# Swift 3: UITabBarController change tab on unwind

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, unwind-segue

I have **UITabBarController**. From the **Home** tab, I segued to a **ThankYouVC**.

When I unwind from ThankYouVC, I want to change the selected tab.

What I've tried:

HomeVC

```
@IBAction func unwindToMain(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("unwind")
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

The console log prints *unwind*, but **doesn't change** the **index**.

Another attempt:

```
enum Notifications: String, NotificationName {
    case QRDoneNotification
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(unwindCallBack), name: Notification.Name("QRDoneNotification"), object: nil)
}

@IBAction func unwindToMain(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("unwind")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notifications.QRDoneNotification.name, object: nil)
}

func unwindCallBack() {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Still no luck!!

Help me out.

Comment: How are you Segueing to your `ThankYouVC`? Is it a modal "present" segue? Is your TabBarController inside a NavigationController and you're pushing away from the TabBar to the `ThankYouVC`?

Comment: I think your self.tabBarController is nil and that's the reason of your problems. Check this

Comment: @DonMag I'm segueing to ThankYouVC using a Show(e.g Push) segue. No, the TabBar isn't inside a Navigation Controller.

Comment: @MichałKwiecień, self.tabBarController isn't nil. I'm changing the tab in another case and it works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an `unwind segue` *unwinds to the view controller* that holds the function. So that's where you end up.

One solution: subclass `UITabBarController` and put your unwind segue there.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    @IBAction func unwindToMain(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("Unwinding to the custom tab bar controller...")
        selectedIndex = 1
    }

}
```

So, add that class to your project... set the Custom Class of your current UITabBarController to `MyTabBarController`... Assign your Exit / Unwind segue to this new one, and don't forget to delete your existing `unwindToMain()` function and unwind connection.